# N1QL query to update array element by its tailored version

Tags: couchbase

While posting data I used escapeCSV to handle extra comma but the data got some extra /" now I want to update the content by using N1QL, but I'm stuck

```
    "School": [
    {
      "address": "\"257 Shyam Nagar, Indore\"",
      "name": "National Convent"
    }


  Required:-

   "School": [
    {
      "address": "257 Shyam Nagar, Indore",
      "name": "National Convent"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use REPLACE() function

```
UPDATE default d 
SET p.address = REPLACE(p.address, "\"","") FOR p IN d.School END 
WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove them before importing it, N1QL needs a valid JSON. Additionally, you could also use single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `test` ( KEY, VALUE ) 
 VALUES 
 ( 
   'mykey2', 
    {
      'type': '"toy',
      "attributes": {
      'material': 'metal"',
      'color': 'red""',
      'weight': '200gr"',
      'height': '5cm',
      'width': '15cm'
    }
}
```

)

Comment: can it be done with update query or by applying any other String function

Comment: You can use replace https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html#fn-str-replace